# Can not catch error in merge statement

Tags: vb.net, oracle, error-handling, oledb, oledbcommand

Hi I have problem to catch the error in merge statement.
The merge statement will get the following error when run in SQL Plus:
`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER`
When I execute the statement with ExecuteNonQuery in Vb.net will not get any exception.
Is there any way to catch that error in Vb.net without using log errors in merge statement?
EDIT:

```
Try
    Dim count as Interger=0
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQL)
    count = cmd .ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex as Exception
    ... Respond ...
End Try
```

Sample Merge Statement with error:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_A a USING
(
    SELECT ID,SUM(AMOUNT) AMOUNT
    FROM TABLE_B b
    GROUP BY ID
) b
ON ( b.ID=a.ID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET a.AMOUNT=a.AMOUNT+b.AMOUNT 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (ID, DT, AMOUNT) VALUES (b.ID, 0, b.AMOUNT);
```

The SQL Plus will get error at the insert but Vb.net can not catch.
The data type for field DT is DATE.

Comment: It would be good if you show us your code.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B sample code added.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B sample merge statement added.

Comment: What is the need to insert a **zero-length** string for **DATE**? Just remove the `dt` from insert and it would anyway be NULL for the newly inserted rows. I am contemplating how would you get `ORA-00932`. Can you post your SQL*Plus session. Post a working test case, so that we can reproduce what you claim.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B that the sample of merge statement that can not catch by Vb,net but SQL Plus will get the error.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 3:
My bad - in that case, I think you'll have to subscribe to oleDbConnection.InfoMessage event and check for applicable SQL-00932 messages after the MERGE command.  I don't see any equivalent property to FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors in OLE-DB (which, again, seems totally backwards...).

EDIT 2:
It appears there's a default threshold that will cause vb.net to ignore certain SQL exceptions (can't fathom the rationale behind such a decision).  Regardless, I think if you do the following, you should see the exception raised.

```
cmd.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
```

End EDIT2

EDIT: I just read the problem a bit closer.  If the vb.net execution is not throwing any exception at all, that would indicate that you're not running the exact same statement in both.  My initial guess is that you're passing a date parameter that is passing SQL Plus string variable incorrectly as `01/01/2015` (which is 1 divided by 1 divided by 2015) and vb.net variable correctly as `'01/01/2015'` (that is, as a string with quotation marks).
End EDIT

I have no idea what you mean by "using log errors in merge statement", but it sounds like you just need the syntax for using the vb.net try-catch syntax to catch and act on Oracle errors.

From here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=467119

Pertinent code snippet:

```
Try  
... Sql here ...
Catch ex as OleDbException
... Respond to error here ...
End Try
```

Comment: I using same statement is SQL Plus and Vb.net. I try OleDbException already it doesnt throw any exception.

Comment: Try forcing an SQL error, e.g. add WHERE 1=1/0 to the SQL, and run in vb.net - this should tell if the vb.net execution is actually hiding SQL exceptions.  If that's not the case, we'd need to see the MERGE statement to know what could be triggering it to fail in SQL Plus.  First sanity check should be that you're connecting both sessions to same database/account.  Next check would be that all date-related conversions are explicit (i.e. TO_DATE(arg1,'DD-MON-YYYY') rather than TO_DATE(arg1)).  Beyond that, you'll prob. need to post actual MERGE for more insight.

Comment: Scratch all that; think I found the explanation - updating answer

Comment: I using OleDb not SqlClient.